# Media buttons type a zero character

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, media-buttons

After updating to 13.10, pressing a multimedia button (volume, media playback, and wifi controls) types a zero character '0', as well as performing its desired function. I'm using an hp dv7 laptop. How can I stop this?

Comment: I have this exact same problem too, using Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04) on an HP-dv7 laptop. Seems quite specific.
I can confirm the media keys work exactly the same way as the 0 key placed above o and p, as the character written changes based on the keyboard layout and modifiers used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent update in 14.04 fixed this issue for me.

If anyone figures out what caused it, or what update fixed it, post and I'll accept that answer.